# ggplot: a histogram that counts variable x and shows the average of variable y above the bin

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

```
test_data <-  data.frame(x = runif(20, 0, 10), y = runif(20, 0, 10))

ggplot(test_data, aes(x)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)

test_data <- test_data %>% arrange(x) 
test_list <- list()
for(i in 1:10){
    test_list[[i]] <- test_data %>% filter( x < i & x > i-1)
}
test_list 

test_means <- c()
for(i in 1:10){test_means[i] <- mean(test_list[[i]]$y)}
test_means
```

Hey Y'all,

I'm trying to learn more about histograms and ggplot2. What I want to do is plot a histogram using variable `x`, I then want to get the mean of variable `y` for the subgroup represented in each bin, and finally I want to place this mean above the bin in the histogram.

This question is two fold:

a) Is there a `ggplot2` function (or any other function for that matter) that can get the mean of `y` for each bin-subgroup. Right now I can only think of making a `for()` function that iterates from the min to the max of the `x` variable by the `binwidth`. It isn't very clean or concise...

b) Does `ggplot2` provide a way of putting up a variable, such as the newly identified mean of `y` for each bin, on top of the corresponding bin?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing built-in to the `stat_bin()` function (which `geom_histogram()` calls) to do what you ask but it's not too hard (or un-[clean|concise]) to do what you ask:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(15) # reproducible

test_data <-  data.frame(x = runif(20, 0, 10), 
                         y = runif(20, 0, 10))

gg <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1, fill="#2166ac", color="white")

mean_bin <- function(df) {
  filter(test_data, x > df$xmin & x <= df$xmax) %>% 
    summarise(μ=mean(y), ct=df$count[1]) %>% 
    mutate(μ=ifelse(is.nan(μ), NA, μ))
}

group_by(ggplot_build(gg)$data[[1]], x) %>% 
  do(mean_bin(.)) %>%
  ungroup() -> bin_means


gg <- gg + geom_text(data=bin_means, 
                     aes(x, ct, label=sprintf("μ(y)=%3.2f", μ)), 
                     vjust=0, nudge_y=0.1, size=2.5)
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0, 4.5))
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg
```

[image]

You have to do `<= df$xmax` since `geom_histogram()/stat_bin()` right-closes the bins by default.

Comment: You are awesome! This was incredibly informative. I learned so much about both `ggplot2` and `r` in general. I can't thank you enough for your answer! I ended  up making a shiny app with this and just figuring out which variables referred to which function was an incredibly useful exercise. Also, can you use 'μ' in `r` or did you use that just for demonstrative purposes? 'μ' doesn't seem to be a proper character in my version of `r` . Again, YOU ARE AWESOME!

Comment: totally valid character at least in my UTF-8 OS X environment. Super glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can try base R:

```
# data
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(x = runif(20, 0, 10), y = runif(20, 0, 10))
# plot the histogram,  save the parameters in n 
n <- hist(d$x, ylim = c(0, max(d$x)))
# get the x-binning, saved in n$breakes and save this in d$bins
d$bins <- .bincode(d$x,breaks = n$breaks)
# aggregate to get the y mean per bin group
a <- aggregate(d$y, list(d$bins), mean)
# add the segments
segments(x0 =  n$breaks[-length(n$breaks)], y0 = a$x, x1 = n$breaks[-1], y1 = a$x, col = "red")
# add text
text(x =  n$breaks +1, y = a$x, labels = round(a$x,2), pos = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is pretty simple and straight forward. This was really helpful. I learned a lot and had no clue that `base r` offered so much control. I really like the idea of using the actually mean number to determine the height of the label. Thank you so much!